# I am trying to access a bunch of VMs hosted over Google cloud remotely but am facing an error with the zone flag, even after specifying zone in CSV

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am trying to access a bunch of VMs using a PowerShell script from my local machine. I have access to all the projects over which the VMs are hosted. To do that, I am giving three inputs - the instance name, the project ID and the zone in which the VM is hosted. But I'm getting this error:

```
`python.exe : ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.describe) Underspecified resource [gcp8265tstapp01]. Specify the [--zone] 
flag.
At C:\Users\nbhattacharyya2\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.ps1:114 char:3
+   & "$cloudsdk_python" $run_args_array
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: (gcloud.... [--zone] flag.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`
```

My script is as follows:

```
$csvFilePath = "C:\Users\nbhattacharyya2\Desktop\File.csv"
Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath | ForEach-Object {
    $projectId = $_.ProjectID
    $vmName = $_.VMName
    $osInfo = gcloud compute instances describe $vmName --project $projectId --format="value(guestOsFeatures)" --quiet
    $osType = if ($osInfo -match "WINDOWS") {
        "Windows"
    } elseif ($osInfo -match "LINUX") {
        "Linux"
    } else {
        "Unknown"
    }
    Write-Host "VM Name: $vmName, OS Type: $osType"
}
```

This is just a dummy code to check if it is working, where I just check the OS of the Vms.

I am trying to fetch details of instances hosted over GCP remotely. The CSV is formatted properly.

Comment: Where are you adding the zone? I do not see it.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/tools/powershell/docs/create-manage